# future example of akka does not work

Tags: akka, actor, future

I try to run the example but I cannot figure out why it keep appear the error at the Await, type mismatch, expected: Awaitable, actual: Future[Any]

```
    import akka.actor.{Actor, Props, ActorSystem}
    import akka.pattern.ask
    import scala.concurrent.Await
    import scala.concurrent.duration._
    import akka.util.Timeout

    val system = ActorSystem("MySystem")
    val test = system.actorOf(Props(new TestFuture), name = "father")
    implicit val timeout = Timeout(60)
    val future = test ? "abc"
    val result = Await.result(future, timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[String]

    println(result)
```

Is that any problem with the import because I run the example before and it work well, but now when turn in to my project, it appear the error, so I return to the sample code and delete all library and re-import then the error appear too !

Comment: What version of scala and akka are you using?

Comment: Is it an IntelliJ error ?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code, can you please provide the akka version and scala version?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old etc...

I had the same problem and have just found the reason: wrong import - 
scalaZ.concurrent.Future instead of scala.concurrent.Future

This happened by picking the wrong import form the intellij prompt and then the error shown does not tell you its a scalaZ future, so could be really frustrating.

Hope this helps someone.